# Failed to allocate a 1814412 byte allocation with 59912 free bytes in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I tried to extend `ImageView` class and in `OnDraw` method, I am creating a circle and trying to display image only in that circle in order to get a rounded `ImageView`.

I am using this `RoundedImageView` in `ListView`.

This piece of code is running fine initially, but after having 4-5 scrolls of `ListView`, its throwing an exception with message "Failed to allocate a 1814412 byte allocation with 59912 free bytes".

the same piece of code is running perfect in eclipse even with more than 300 list items but in xamarin its throwing this exception

Can anyone help me out?

Below is the code:

```
public class RoundedImageView : ImageView {

    public RoundedImageView(Context context) : base(context) {
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context,attrs) {
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle) {
    }

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Drawable drawable = Drawable;

        if (drawable == null){
            return;
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        Bitmap bit = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).Bitmap;

        try {
            bitmap = bit.Copy(Bitmap.Config.Argb8888, true);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            string temp = exp.Message;
            base.OnDraw(canvas);
            return;
        }

        int _width = Width;
        int _height = Height;

        Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, _width <= _height ? _width : _height);
        canvas.DrawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0,0, null);
    }

    public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius)  {
        Bitmap _bitmap;

        if(bitmap.Width != radius || bitmap.Height != radius) {
            try {
                _bitmap = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, radius, radius, false);
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                string temp = exp.Message;
                _bitmap = bitmap;
                return _bitmap;
            }
        } else {
            _bitmap = bitmap;
        }

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(_bitmap.Width,_bitmap.Height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, _bitmap.Width, _bitmap.Height);

        paint.AntiAlias = true;
        paint.FilterBitmap = true;
        paint.Dither = true;

        canvas.DrawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

        paint.Color = Color.ParseColor("#7f00ff");

        canvas.DrawCircle(_bitmap.Width / 2 ,
                          _bitmap.Height / 2 ,
                          _bitmap.Width / 2 - 0.2f,
                          paint);

        paint.SetXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn));
        canvas.DrawBitmap(_bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to recycle all the `Bitmap` instances you are creating.

This could help:

```
protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
{

    Drawable drawable = Drawable;

    if (drawable == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    Bitmap bit = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).Bitmap;
    try
    {
        bitmap = bit.Copy(Bitmap.Config.Argb8888, true);
        bit.Recycle();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        string temp = exp.Message;
        base.OnDraw(canvas);
        return;
    }

    int _width = Width;
    int _height = Height;

    using (Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, _width <= _height ? _width : _height))
    {
        canvas.DrawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0,0, null);
        roundBitmap.Recycle();
        bitmap.Recycle();
    }
}


public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius) 
{
    Bitmap _bitmap;
    if(bitmap.Width != radius || bitmap.Height != radius)
    {
        try
        {
            _bitmap = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, radius, radius, false);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            string temp = exp.Message;
            _bitmap = bitmap;
            return _bitmap;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(_bitmap.Width,_bitmap.Height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);

    using(Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output))
    using(Paint paint = new Paint())
    {
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, _bitmap.Width, _bitmap.Height);

        paint.AntiAlias = true;
        paint.FilterBitmap = true;
        paint.Dither = true;

        canvas.DrawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

        paint.Color = Color.ParseColor("#7f00ff");


        canvas.DrawCircle(_bitmap.Width / 2 ,
                          _bitmap.Height / 2 ,
                          _bitmap.Width / 2 - 0.2f,
                          paint);


        paint.SetXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn));
        canvas.DrawBitmap(_bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        _bitmap.Recycle();
    }

    return output;
}
```

Also it is not very efficient to create so many instances of objects in the `OnDraw` method, so consider if you can move something out of it.

Also consider if you can just use a Drawable like in the Xamarin Store sample: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-store-app/blob/master/XamarinStore.Droid/Views/CircleDrawable.cs

Comment: Where exactly is it throwing?

Comment: at bit.Recycle() only

Comment: And the entire stack trace is?

Comment: not able to paste stack trace in single comment. how can I paste a large text here ?